# AMD OpenCL 2.0 SVM(Shared Virtual Memory) per allocation size and total maximum size

Tags: size, opencl

Does anyone know is there any size limitation of using clSVMAlloc(). My code runs correctly when the total size of memory allocated by clSVMAlloc() is <120MB but fails(kernel results are not correct) when >120MB. Thank you.

Comment: No, there is not. If the alloc does not return an error then the memory is properly allocated. Check your kernel code can handle properly the new size.

Comment: Thank you for your information. Actually, the kernel code should be no problem. Because the kernel result is correct when I use traditional clCreateBuffer() for the same input(>120MB). That implies the problem may due to the CPU side. However, the SVM version success when input size <120MB, which means cpu side is properly set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced similar problem and update to the latest Catalyst (15.7) fixed the problem. [Link](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download)

Also update to the final version of AMD APP SDK v3.0 in case you are still on Beta. [Link](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/opencl-zone/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/)

---

**Driver reinstallation procedure on Ubuntu 14.04**

Download drivers: `fglrx-core_15.200-0ubuntu1_amd64_ub_14.01.deb` and `fglrx_15.200-0ubuntu1_amd64_ub_14.01.deb` from http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Ubuntu%20x86%2064

Remove old drivers:

```
sudo dpkg -r fglrx-dev fglrx-amdcccle fglrx fglrx-core
sudo dpkg --purge fglrx-dev fglrx-amdcccle fglrx fglrx-core
reboot
```

Install new drivers:

```
sudo dpkg -i fglrx-core_15.200-0ubuntu1_amd64_ub_14.01.deb 
sudo dpkg -i fglrx_15.200-0ubuntu1_amd64_ub_14.01.deb
reboot
```

Verify if the drivers are correctly installed:

```
dmesg | grep fglrx | grep module
```

---

**AMD APP SDK reinstallation on Ubuntu 14.04**

1. Install new SDK
2. Make sure everything is correctly set in these config files/locations: `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/amdapp_x86.conf`, `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/amdapp_x86_64.conf`, `/etc/OpenCL/vendors`
3. Manually remove old SDK

Comment: Very grad to see it can be fixed. I installed the Catalyst driver by apt-get install fglrx and I can see the version is 15.20.2[Feb 27,2015], and the libOpenCL.so showing date(Aug 18, 06:19), which should be the Catalyst 15.7 because when I downloaded the Catalyst 15.7, the debian is fglrx_15.200-0ubuntu1_amd64_ub_14.01.deb. The problem is not solved. Also i updated the Beta to AMDAPPSDK-v3.0.

Comment: @770966796 I've updated my answer with driver and SDK reinstallation procedure on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Thanks very much for your efforts. Here is what I get from dmesg. [    2.420666] fglrx: module license 'Proprietary. (C) 2002 - ATI Technologies, Starnberg, GERMANY' taints kernel.
[    2.431574] fglrx: module verification failed: signature and/or  required key missing - tainting kernel
[    2.468329] <6>[fglrx] module loaded - fglrx 15.20.2 [Feb 27 2015] with 1 minors
I can't see amdapp_x86.conf amdapp_x86_64.conf. I thought NEW SDK has nothing to do with this problem, because the libOpenCL.so is still from /usr/lib/libOpenCL.so.  BTW, my machine is Radeon R7, only supports coarse grain SVM.

Comment: Awesome, the library needs to be from NEW SDK.  Solved. Why AMD doesn't point out the libraray need to be from SDK instead of fglrx.....

Comment: From my experience on R9 295 the coarse grain SVM is faster than cl_mem but fine grain SVM is still slower ... Don't forget to accept the answer if you are happy.